# Why would you call jQuery's unbind('change') method to trigger a change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbind

Below is some JavaScript I have extracted from a larger script that is used to allow AJAX style image uploads as part of a markdown editor like StackOverflow uses.

As soon as you select an image from your computer using an HTML Form File Field, it triggers the script to do an image upload and returns the URL of the new uploaded image.

This line in particular is making me curious though and I need help understanding it better please...

`$file.unbind('change').ajaxfileupload()`

I understand the `unbind('change')` is triggering the upload to happen with the `change` event.  However I am confused as to why it would be using `unbind()`

As I understand that function to basically be used to remove an event handler?  My logic is thinking it would instead be using `bind()` but it;s using `unbind()` instead and it just works!  But I have no idea as to why.
What am I missing here?  Is there enough code here to answer my question?

Am I correct in thinking that `unbind()` is used to remove/stop an event handler from functioning anymore?  If I am right, then I am not sure why it would be attached to an element that is supposedly doing the opposite and is waiting for an image to trigger an upload?

Hopefully this all makes sense to someone and they can point me in the right direction, a simple to understand answer would be wonderful, thanks!

```
var $file = $('input[type=file]', $dialog);

// upload
$file.unbind('change').ajaxfileupload({
    action: $file.attr('data-action'),
    params: {
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    onStart: uploadStart,
    //onComplete: uploadComplete
    'onComplete': function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

Comment: `unbind('change')` doesnt trigger a change event. It just removes any event handlers currently on that element(s). The unbinding of the previously bound events is probably to prevent duplicate processing of the files.

Comment: @PatrickEvans is right. Probably a cleaner way to do this is to use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and rebind when necessary.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Now it is making more sense after reading abut it more however what threw me off and still does somewhat is in the code I see nowhere else where there is anything triggering the actual file upload!  With there being no other apparent Event triggering the upload, it makes it look like that was doing it, I guess I need to try and track down where that even is really defined then, thanks for the info

Comment: @PatrickEvans after more review of the full code I have, there really is nowhere else where this even is defined so it does appear that perhaps even though this doesnt trigger a change event, it seems that in the process of removing the event that it still then calls the script function for `.ajaxfileupload()` which in turn is triggering/doing the upload process all in one step.  SOrt os misleading/sloppy IMO

Comment: So you are saying without any user interaction the onchange event is triggered and some file gets uploaded through whatever plugin you are using?

Comment: I am using a JavaScript library called PageDown, it is what SO uses for it;s Markdown editor.  The code in discussion is inside code that is triggered to run when the add image button is clicked which opens a Dialog window.  In this dialog, simply selecting an image triggers it to start uploading right away though which is what led me to think that the posted `change`  was the event originally.  Not really important was just trying to understand it better as I am modifying it more to function more like StackOverflows image uploads from computer and from URL capabilities behave

Answer (score 2):

My thinking is that the `unbind()` is in fact removing an event handler for the change event.  If we look at the jQuery docs for [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) there seems to be no ambiguity.  So what then might the code be doing?

My guess is that somewhere previously a change event was added and we want to remove it.  The logic of `$file.unbind('change').ajaxfileupload(....)` says to me ... first we remove any event handler for the change event from the jQuery object referenced by `$file` and then execute the widget called `ajaxfileupload`.